# ¿Por qué esta petición GET en Volley retorna error?

Tags: android, url, get, volley

Estoy haciendo una petición get con volley, tengo el siguiente código:

```
String url = AppContext.getGlobalContext().getString(R.string.ws_url_base) + "persona/information?idUser=" + idPersona+"&type=Resgistrado";
        final Map<String, String> mHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            mHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(RestRequest.RestMethod.GET, url, null, mHeaders);

            **BaseUsers.getClient().sendAsync(restRequest, new RestClient.AsyncRequestCallback() {...}**
```

El problema es que cuando llega a la última línea de código va a un catch que retorna:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.net.URI.toString()' on a null object reference

Yo ya comprobé la respuesta de la url y se supone que la solicitud es exitosa.

Comment: A mi tu código no me suena a `Volley`. Parecería como si estuvieras mezclando `AsynTask` u otra librería con `Volley`. ¿Precisamente, qué es lo que hace la línea que muestras entre `**`? ¿Si tú evitas esa línea y muestras un Log de `restRequest` muestra algo?

Comment: @A.Cedano por lo de RestRequest pense que era de C# pero veo que usa : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/android_native_classes_restclient.htm no tiene que ver con Volley.